# Return a non-string object when a class is referenced after initialisation

Tags: python-3.x

I cannot find an answer after some searching. I am trying to make a make-shift "underscore" for a python interpretor, and would like it to both act like the `_` in a python console, but also be able to store more than one previous result.

So far I have tried

```
class Underscore():
    def __init__(self):
        self.deque = collections.deque([], 10)
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.deque[index]
    def append(self, obj):
        self.deque.appendleft(obj)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.deque[0]
```

With the idea being that I can access the last output of a command line session with either `_` *or* `_[0]`, then be able to access more previous results with `_[i]`.

The problem I am having though is that `__repr__` is only able to return a string, which is not what I want, but means that this example code breaks the class:

```
>>> datetime.utcnow()
<DateTime ...>
# Behind the scenes, I call _.append(returned_datetime)
>>> _[0].month # works, but not the most ideal way
>>> _.month # crashes because repr did not return string.
```

So what I'm asking is: Is it possible to do this in any way? or is this whole idea a pipe dream?

Comment: I'm programming my own interractive session via a bot interface through Discord. I dont have `_` available to me natively, which is why I want to reimplement `_` myself. I'm basically just throwing all the variables alongside `_` into a locked down `eval()` command.

Comment: `_` is just a normal variable that gets assigned the previous value by the REPL. It isn't some special object. When an object is referenced, a string isn't returned (unless your object is a string), the *object itself* is returned

Comment: So does that mean what I want isn't possible then? That's a shame...
Guess the next best option is to just have `_` and the deque be 2 different variables...